# Tagged template inner behaviour

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why this happens. `f` returns an array, yet a deep check returns `true`.

```
const tag = (string, ...values) => string
const f = x => tag`hello ${x}`
console.log(f(1) === f(2)) //prints true
```

Source https://twitter.com/justinfagnani/status/1247652729922531328

Answer (score 0):

Method `f` returns `strings` array according to the `tag` template literal and in both cases it returns the same array reference. Output changes when you initialize second (same body) template literal.

```
const tag = (strings, ...values) => strings
const f = x => tag`hello ${x}`
const g = x => tag`hello ${x}`

console.log(f(1)) //prints [ 'hello ', '' ]
console.log(f(2)) //prints [ 'hello ', '' ]
console.log(g(1)) //prints [ 'hello ', '' ]
console.log(g(2)) //prints [ 'hello ', '' ]

console.log(f(1) === f(1)) //prints true
console.log(f(1) === g(1)) //prints false
console.log(g(2) === g(1)) //prints true
```

**2.**
Each time we execute new template literal for the first time (initialization) we create new instance of array, but the array of strings is kept in memory and literal passes its reference.

```
const x = 5
const tag = (strings, ...values) => strings
const f = tag`hello ${x}`

console.log((tag`hello ${x}`) === (tag`hello ${x}`)); //prints false
console.log(f === f);  //prints true
```

Comment: how does it returns the same array reference? Following your explanation I would expect `function a() { return [1]}; console.log(a() === a())` to print `true` but it's not.

Comment: That's incorrect assumption. You compare in your example different objects. Literal creates only one array of strings and passes each time reference to it.

Comment: Do you have more concerns about template literal?